# jsonlite::toJSON too many `[]` brackets in R - unbox json

Tags: r, tibble, jsonlite

I am building an api at the moment which has several layers of information. At the moment I am using tibbles and nesting the information under columns:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  APICallTimeGMT      Error                some_data       
  <dttm>              <list>               <list>          
1 2018-10-19 11:43:10 <data.frame [1 × 2]> <tibble [2 × 3]>
```

When I then turn this into `JSON` using `jsonlite::toJSON`, I get a lot list `[]` brackets. Is there a way to turn these specific objects into a json object instead of a list. So, what class (instead of data.frame) should the nested object be?

Current output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Here is the `dput(x)` for reproducibility:

```
structure(list(APICallTimeGMT = structure(1539949390.26164, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Error = list(structure(list(msg = structure(1L, .Label = "OK", class = "factor"), 
    status = 200), .Names = c("msg", "status"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")), some_data = list(structure(list(
    Outcome = c("Case1", "Case2"), predictions = list(structure(list(
        ClassA = 0.4, ClassB = 0.1, ClassC = 0.5), .Names = c("ClassA", 
    "ClassB", "ClassC"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(ClassA = 0.4, ClassB = 0.1, ClassC = 0.5), .Names = c("ClassA", 
        "ClassB", "ClassC"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")), 
    meta = list(structure(list(model = structure(1L, .Label = "Awesome AI", class = "factor"), 
        runs = 55), .Names = c("model", "runs"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(model = structure(1L, .Label = "Awesome AI", class = "factor"), 
        runs = 55), .Names = c("model", "runs"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Outcome", "predictions", "meta"
)))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .Names = c("APICallTimeGMT", "Error", 
"some_data"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Stéphane Laurent was close. It would seem that the problem is that if the data is within nested tibbles, `auto-unbox = TRUE`, somehow fails. To print the data above correctly, I used `mutate` + `purrr`:

```
library(jsonlite)

x_unboxed <- x %>% 
  mutate(Error = map(Error, ~.x %>% unbox),
         some_data = map(some_data, ~.x %>% 
                           mutate(predictions = map(predictions, ~.x %>% unbox),
                                  meta = map(meta, ~.x %>% unbox)))) %>% 
  unbox

x_unboxed %>% toJSON(., pretty = T)
```

Comment: Ah nice, you've found a solution. I have just written an ugly solution (converting each dataframe to a list), but no need to post it now. I didn't know the `unbox` function.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case where you're just using `list`s, the [`auto_unbox`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.8.4/topics/unbox) flag does do the trick:

```r
> jsonlite::toJSON(list(name = "test", value = 2))
{"name":["test"],"value":[2]} 
> jsonlite::toJSON(list(name = "test", value = 2), auto_unbox=TRUE)
{"name":"test","value":2}
```

I'm glad I could see [@Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent)'s deleted answer as this is the common answer to this question.